# Property in object exists but is undefined

Tags: javascript, atom-editor

I have an object that in javascript that does have the property that I'm looking for, but when I try to access the property it's undefined.

Here is my code:

```js
for (ret of value.methods[values[1]].ret) {
    var names = Object.keys(ret)
    console.log(JSON.stringify(ret, null, 2))
    if (names[0] == "N/A") {
      methodString = methodString.concat(` ${ret.type}`);
    }
    else {
      methodString = methodString.concat(` ${names[0]} (${ret.type}),`);
    }
  }
```

On the 3rd line of the code sample above I'm printing out the object and this is the console output

```json
{
  "newPosition": {
    "type": "table"
  }
}
```

So `type` does exist inside of `newPosition` but when I try to access it on either line 5 or line 8 it says it's undefined. When checking if the property exists with `hasOwnProperty` member function it returns `false`.

I'm really stumped by this and I don't know what to do. I've looked at a lot of answers here on stack overflow and none of them have provided me with an answer to this problem.

Comment: What does `console.log(ret)` output? Note the absence of `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: @JeremyThille it's the same just as an object instead of a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `ret.type` *is* `undefined`.

What you're trying to get is`ret.newPosition.type`

Comment: Thanks! I believe I was thinking that I didn't need that since because of what the console was showing me. But I guess I'm just tired of looking at this code :P

Comment: Totally. I had to run it because I was also confused ;) Where I am at in the object level trips me up all the time